# Can RAM with significantly lowered temperature still be accessed normally?

Tags: memory, cpu, temperature

If I significantly lower the temperature of RAM using those dust cleaners (I'm following the method outlined in this paper: http://citpsite.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/oldsite-htdocs/pub/coldboot.pdf) so that I stop it's contents from being erased once power is cut, and then restart the computer, if the RAM is still that cold and also surrounded by the liquid, is it okay to restart the computer and access the contents of RAM? Or do I need to wait?

Answer (score 1):

You could access it with specialized tools, but you wouldn't be able to boot up and be in the same state as when you shutdown. The RAM still has data on it, but you wouldn't be able to launch an application and use that data.

RAM is volatile memory, meaning that after the computer is shutdown the data is erased and entirely lost. Hard disks are non-volatile, meaning that they can go into a powered-off state, and when power is returned the data is still there. What this paper is saying, is that if you make the RAM sufficiently cold, the data degrades slower, and is less volatile than RAM under normal operating conditions.

Computers expect RAM to be volatile though, and so when your computer boots back up, it doesn't look in your RAM to see if anything is still there, it just assumes that it's all empty or junk.

If you're trying to turn your computer off, and return it to the same state that the computer was previously in, that won't work. It means that while the data is not entirely lost, it's still recoverable, but not very likely not usable.

Comment: I read the paper I linked, and they provided the tools to recover the data. I'm all set on that front. I just want to know, I guess from an electrical standpoint, if I'm okay booting the computer with all that liquid surrounding the RAM and with the RAM being at that temperature.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're asking. If you look on page 7 they specify that the computer is powered on when they start cooling the RAM, so it looks like that it is physically possible.  I wouldn't be surprised if it damaged your RAM in the long run, since it may cause some contraction and expansion.

Comment: After browsing the internet for a bit, it looks like the liquid doesn't cause short circuits or anything that would damage the electronics, but I definitely wouldn't try this project with a computer I care about.

Comment: Thanks for your help man. I'm trying to recover very important files on my frozen computer, so unfortunately I do have to try it on a computer I do care about.

Comment: Also, the liquid likely wouldn't just hit ram, it would hit other things as well. Is that still okay? Is it cool to email the authors about things like this or would that be inappropriate?

Comment: @Rayman, to be clear, you should be willing to lose the computer you perform this on. If the data isn't *massively* more valuable than this, don't bother. There's a good chance it won't work anyway, as you are probably using DDR3 RAM. Even if it does work, all you'll have is the contents of RAM. Even if you are a developer, this is probably useless to you.

Comment: The researchers seem like they're fairly experienced (one's a Tor project founder, the other is a senior EFF member, Princeton Ph.D. students, etc.) and one of the suggestions they themselves mention to access the contents is rebooting the same computer. Also, wouldn't they disclose things like this? And aren't the dust cleaners they suggest meant to be used inside computer cases?

Comment: Also, it's mostly notepad/text-editor notes, wouldn't those be easily identifiable and recoverable within ram? And the paper authors recovered images and cryptographic keys from RAM too, and I'm not going for anything so complicated. So the contents should be useful, right?

Comment: @Adam What special tools are you referring to? Does anyone else have any tools in mind?

Comment: Special tools I was referring to was software to inspect and recover the data from the RAM, but as you said, that paper covers that.

Comment: Just as a note, this should be the absolute last resort final thing you try, because even if you do recover the data, it is extremely unlikely you will retrieve it in one piece, it is likely that the data will be overwritten, lost, or at best degraded, when the recovery attempt is made. If you attempt to do this, be sure to write an article on this, I'd be interested to read it.

Comment: Adam, thanks, you've really been helpful. Preventing data loss is exactly the reason I want to lower the temperature. If the temperature is lowered using those standard dust cleaner cans, as was done in the paper, the authors found that 99.9% of the data in RAM remains intact, and consistently so.

Comment: Once I try this, which will likely be tonight, I'll definitely update this post with the results.